# Power BI Analysis Services Connector and Personal Gateway

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I don't understand the difference between Analysis Services Connector and Personal Gateway. It seems to me that they have the same role.

Answer (score 0):

Both the tools are synonymous, SSAS Connector(Analysis services connector) is an old tool which has been replaced by Power BI gateway. I was not able to refresh my multidimensional analysis cubes using SSAS connector and once I used power BI gateway I was able to get refreshed data in power BI. In Fact power BI gateway has some major enhancements like SSAS connector does not support multidimensional cubes, while the new power BI personal gateway has the ability to connect your on premise multidimensional cubes to Power BI. you can have more insights on these links

- http://biinsight.com/power-bi-and-ssas-multidimensional/
- http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2015/07/power-bi-personal-gateway/comment-page-1/

As per [this link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-gateway-enterprise-now-supports-live-connections-to-analysis-services-and-sap-hana/), Microsoft recommends to upgrade Analysis service connector with Power BI Gateway as it gives 2X performance improvements.